# How to Show AJAX Response into Alert

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code which I currently show the response of an AJAX request in the `innerHTML` of an element, but I want to `alert` the response result instead. How can I do that?

```
function checkforsampleAdded(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('school_name');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    var status = document.getElementById('teststatus').value;
    var tstid = document.getElementById('tstid').value;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url();?>Test/CheckForSampleAdded/" + tstid, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(); 
}
```

Comment: So change the line that set the `innerHTML` to an `alert()`...? Also your question has nothing to do with jQuery or codeigniter so I removed those tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from checking the readyState, I'd recommend you also check the status to be 200

Here's the updated code

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('school_name');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            alert(ajaxRequest.responseText); // alert the data
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks its worked for me.one more thing if __ajaxRequest.responseTest__ emplty do not alert.